# Bad entry in file .//controller.m Argument is not a literal string

Tags: ios, localization, xcode6

I am getting the following error: Argument is not a literal String. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

**strAbout is a dynamic string.**

```
    [btnBack setTitle:NSLocalizedString(strAbout, @"") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Can you post your localization file? also, have you tried passing nill as a second argument instead of @""?

Comment: https://medium.com/ios-apprentice/working-with-localization-905e4052b9de

Comment: [Objective C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html)

Answer (score 2):

The key value and the comment in the NSLocalizedString macro has to be constant, this values are use to create a table of keys with the comments as hints to help the translators. So you can not have a dynamic key because the system will not know what you want to localize.

On the other hand you can have portions dynamic as a Format in case you need to for example a quantity in a text, but if all your text is dynamic you are best by no using NSLocalizedString.

This is an example of use a format in a NSLocalizedString:

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"%@'s Profile", @"{User First Name}'s Profile"), user.name];
```

You can read more about this in the [NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/) where I got the example.

Comment: I'm stuck because you cannot Localize a string dynamically at run time according to this... you cannot load the key from a table and then translate is as you get an error "Bad entry in file xxx.m (line = xx): Argument is not a literal string."

I'm rather surprised by this because often dynamic models are used for string representations, and most people would want to localize the result.